# Change submit button value with Javascript - including line break

Tags: javascript, submit-button

When I define the value of a submit button in HTML, I can cause a line break:

```
<script>
    function change_value() {
        if (document.getElementById('click_me').checked) {
            document.getElementById('next').value='Next';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('next').value='Text with&#13;&#10;line break';
        }
    }
</script>

<form>
    <input id="click_me" type="checkbox" name="click_this" value="1" onclick="change_value()">
    <input id="next" type="submit" value="Text with&#13;&#10;line break">
</form>
```

Before clicking the checkbox, the submit button looks like this:

[image]

But when I set that value using JavaScript, the line breaks are being displayed as text:

[image]

How can I insert a text with line break using JavaScript?

---

*Note.*

This only needs to work in recent versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In js the line break character is `\n`, that should be used when you set the value property

```js
function change_value() {
  if (document.getElementById('click_me').checked) {
    document.getElementById('next').value = 'Next';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('next').value = 'Text with\nline break';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="click_me" type="checkbox" name="click_this" value="1" onclick="change_value()">
<input id="next" type="submit" value="Text with&#13;&#10;line break">
```

Answer (score 1):

[More details about Text formatting on this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting#Multi-line_template_strings)

```
  document.getElementById('click_me').value='Text with \n line break'
```

or

```
document.getElementById('next').value=`Text with 
  line break`;
```

Comment: For some reason your second example does not work for me (on OS X in Firefox). If I actually break the code to a new line, the script stops working completele – even inserting "Next" no longer works, and the console doesn't show any errors.

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
 function change_value() {
      if (document.getElementById('click_me').checked) {
        document.getElementById('next').value = 'Next';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('next').value = 'Text with \n line break';
      }
    }
```